# Can not import copy_reg

Tags: python-2.7, web2py, pythonanywhere

I am hosting my Web2py app on PythonAnyware and have an issue importing copy_reg which web2py apparently needs. In previous versions this was no issue.

The trace back is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):

> ```
> File "/home/richdijk/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 220, in restricted
>   exec ccode in environment
> File "/home/richdijk/web2py/applications/im/models/db.py", line 78, in <module>
>   auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)
> File "/home/richdijk/web2py/gluon/tools.py", line 1784, in define_tables
>    format='%(first_name)s %(last_name)s (%(id)s)'))
> File "/home/richdijk/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 8223, in define_table
>    table = self.lazy_define_table(tablename,*fields,**args)
> File "/home/richdijk/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 8260, in lazy_define_table
>    polymodel=polymodel)
> File "/home/richdijk/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 1122, in create_table
>    sql_fields_old = pickle.load(tfile)
> File "/home/richdijk/web2py/gluon/custom_import.py", line 92, in custom_importer
>   return base_importer(pname, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
> ImportError: No module named copy_reg
> ```

Does anybody know the resolution for this?
Thank you

Comment: Can you import `copy_reg` normally from the Python command line? For Python 2.7, this module should definitely exist, unless your Python installation is incomplete (for Python 3, it's called `copyreg`, but your question is tagged 2-7).

Comment: yes, I can import copy_reg manually, both from the Python prompt and from the Web2py console.

Comment: I made progress and updated the web2py google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/8toVDprfqwM Something was wrong with picked files, not the software.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

Most often you should clear the cache and sessions. Use the appadmin interface to have a gui for this. This solved the issue for me more than once.

Sessions are pickled files which might lead to these problems. For example if you synchronize between different platforms, python versions and maybe sometimes even between upgrades on web2py (though i'm not certain on the latter).