# Django-nose test html error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, code-coverage, django-nose

I'm testing a web application using Django-nose to monitor the code coverage. At first it worked perfectly well, but when trying to generate HTML it fails with the error:

Imput error: No module named copy_reg

It happened after a few times (until then in worked). I tried it on a computer with newly installed django, django-nose and coverage and the very same code works fine. Re-installing django and django-nose didn't help.

Any suggestions? Should I re-install any library or something?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556269/importerror-no-module-named-copy-reg-pickle)?

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023485/can-not-import-copy-reg) ?

Comment: I tried "clearsessions" - there was no output, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by uninstalling coverage.py with pip and installing it using easy_install.