# web2py fails on importing matplotlib modules

Tags: python, matplotlib, web2py, anaconda

I don't quite understand the workings of web2py's `custom_import.py`. I am attempting to import modules from withing `mathplotlib` but I am getting inconsistent results.

My controller `version.py` contains these statements.

```
def import_mathlab_cbook():
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
    return "cbook.__file__ = %r" % cbook.__file__

def import_mathlab_figure():
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    return "Figure.__file__ = %r" % Figure.__file__

def import_mathlab_backends():
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg 
    return "FigureCanvasAgg.__file__ = %r" % FigureCanvasAgg.__file__
```

The import of matplotlib.cbook works fine, but the others produce errors.

```
cbook.__file__ = '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/applications/plotlab/controllers/version.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/gluon/globals.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/applications/plotlab/controllers/version.py", line 41, in import_mathlab_figure
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/gluon/custom_import.py", line 95, in custom_importer
    return base_importer(pname, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.figure


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/applications/plotlab/controllers/version.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/gluon/globals.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/applications/plotlab/controllers/version.py", line 46, in import_mathlab_backends
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
  File "/site/web2py.2.13.4/gluon/custom_import.py", line 95, in custom_importer
    return base_importer(pname, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.backends.backend_agg
```

All of these `import` statements work from the command line and when web2py is run at the command line.

```
# python web2py.py -S welcome -P
web2py Web Framework
Created by Massimo Di Pierro, Copyright 2007-2016
Version 2.13.4-stable+timestamp.2015.12.26.04.59.39
Database drivers available: sqlite3, imaplib, pymysql, pg8000
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 
>>> import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
>>> 
>>> from matplotlib.figure import Figure
>>> 
>>> from  matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
```

I am running `Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32)` and web2py `Version 2.13.4-stable+timestamp.2015.12.26.04.59.39`.

I know that there is a similar question regarding [importing the copy_reg module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023485/can-not-import-copy-reg), but an answer has yet to be accepted for that problem.

Comment: I have also tried copying the `matplotlib` directory under the web2py app's module directory, but then I get `ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: What's the `cbook.__file__` and `matplotlib.figure.__file__` in the command line import,

Comment: They are just there to demonstrate where the file is being imported from. These methods were written for diagnostic purposes. The original code just had the 3 import statements at the start of the file.

Comment: I think that may help others to analysis your problem.